# Email Function without outlook

Tags: html

my client is having a linux server. his demand is to generate an email function only in html and without using default email client like outlook etc. please help me.. what should be the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in only HTML. You must use PHP, ASPX, or another server-side language to accomplish something like this.

[Look into the mail() function provided by PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)